# How to remove li tag by data attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove li tag by data attribute.

> I want to remove 1st ul of child li which has class name like second Base when click.

**My code looks like as below**

```
<div class="box-ul">
  <ul data-id="Base" class="left">
    <li>Base</li>
    <li class="second Base">
      <span data-addedname="SignatureBread" class="close-btn">Signature Bread<a href="#" class="close"></a></span>
      <span data-addedname="Lettuce" class="close-btn">Lettuce<a href="#" class="close"></a></span>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul data-id="Core Filling" class="left">
    <li>Core Filling</li>
    <li class="second CoreFilling">
      <span data-addedname="Steak" class="close-btn">Steak<a href="#" class="close"></a></span>
      <span data-addedname="CrispyChecken" class="close-btn">Crispy Checken<a href="#" class="close"></a></span>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul data-id="Spreads &amp; Cheeses" class="left">
    <li>Spreads &amp; Cheeses</li>
    <li class="second SpreadsCheeses"><span data-addedname="HomemadeHommos(Spread)" class="close-btn">Homemade Hommos (Spread)<a href="#" class="close"></a></span>
      <span data-addedname="ZaatarWithOliveOil(Spread)" class="close-btn">Zaatar With Olive Oil (Spread)<a href="#" class="close"></a></span>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul data-id="Classic Ingredients" class="left">
    <li>Classic Ingredients</li>
    <li class="second ClassicIngredients"><span data-addedname="Lettuce" class="close-btn">Lettuce<a href="#" class="close"></a></span><span data-addedname="Tomato" class="close-btn">Tomato<a href="#" class="close"></a></span><span data-addedname="Cucumber" class="close-btn">Cucumber<a href="#" class="close"></a></span>
      <span data-addedname="Pickles" class="close-btn">Pickles
        <a href="#" class="close"></a>
        </span>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul data-id="Premium Ingredients" class="left">
    <li>Premium Ingredients</li>
    <li class="second PremiumIngredients">
      <span data-addedname="SundriedTomato" class="close-btn">Sundried Tomato<a href="#" class="close"></a></span>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul data-id="Sauces" class="left">
    <li>Sauces</li>
    <li class="second Sauces">
      <span data-addedname="Ketchup*(Classic)" class="close-btn">Ketchup* (Classic)<a href="#" class="close"></a></span>
      <span data-addedname="Mayo(Classic)" class="close-btn">Mayo (Classic)<a href="#" class="close"></a></span>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

> I want to like this output. Here remove li of first ul.

```
<div class="box-ul">
  <ul data-id="Base" class="left">
    <li>Base</li>
  </ul>

  <ul data-id="Core Filling" class="left">
    <li>Core Filling</li>
    <li class="second CoreFilling">
      <span data-addedname="Steak" class="close-btn">Steak<a href="#" class="close"></a></span>
      <span data-addedname="CrispyChecken" class="close-btn">Crispy Checken<a href="#" class="close"></a></span>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul data-id="Spreads &amp; Cheeses" class="left">
    <li>Spreads &amp; Cheeses</li>
    <li class="second SpreadsCheeses">
      <span data-addedname="HomemadeHommos(Spread)" class="close-btn">Homemade Hommos (Spread)<a href="#" class="close"></a></span>
      <span data-addedname="ZaatarWithOliveOil(Spread)" class="close-btn">Zaatar With Olive Oil (Spread)<a href="#" class="close"></a></span>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul data-id="Classic Ingredients" class="left">
    <li>Classic Ingredients</li>
    <li class="second ClassicIngredients">
      <span data-addedname="Lettuce" class="close-btn">Lettuce<a href="#" class="close"></a></span><span data-addedname="Tomato" class="close-btn">Tomato<a href="#" class="close"></a></span>
      <span data-addedname="Cucumber" class="close-btn">Cucumber<a href="#" class="close"></a></span>
      <span data-addedname="Pickles" class="close-btn">Pickles
        <a href="#" class="close"></a>
        </span>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul data-id="Premium Ingredients" class="left">
    <li>Premium Ingredients</li>
    <li class="second PremiumIngredients">
      <span data-addedname="SundriedTomato" class="close-btn">Sundried Tomato<a href="#" class="close"></a></span>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul data-id="Sauces" class="left">
    <li>Sauces</li>
    <li class="second Sauces"><span data-addedname="Ketchup*(Classic)" class="close-btn">Ketchup* (Classic)<a href="#" class="close"></a></span><span data-addedname="Mayo(Classic)" class="close-btn">Mayo (Classic)<a href="#" class="close"></a></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: something like this `$('.box-ul ul:first').find('.Base').remove()`

Comment: Thank you Akshay. But it works only for first not any other ul of li.

Comment: can you print your required output there ?

Comment: Please check my required output  Deep Kakkar.

Comment: You should seriously consider changing the title of your question.

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/926vogLk/

```
$('li.second.Base').click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

or

if you want to remove first li of ul

```
$('li.second.Base').click(function() {
    $(this).prev().remove();
});
```

Comment: i'm not sure his required

Comment: I agree. It's quite hard to discern what he wants too. This will do the job i think.

Comment: may be.. he want to remove first li of ul

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove only first ul then try @Akhsay mentioned solution. Or if you want to remove any ul with specific class or data attribute then do this.

```
$("ul[data-id=Base]").find("li.base").remove()
```

Or

`$("li.Base").remove()`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I hunderstood right but:
$("li.second.Base").parent().remove()
might help you

Comment: This will remove the entire UL, he just wants to remove `<li class="second Base">...</li>`

Comment: then just: $("li.second.Base").remove()

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $('.second').on('click',function(){
    
    $(this).fadeOut(300,function(){$(this).remove() });
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-ul">


                 <ul data-id="Base" class="left">
                    <li>Base</li>
                    <li class="second Base"><span data-addedname="SignatureBread" class="close-btn">Signature Bread<a href="#" class="close"></a></span><span data-addedname="Lettuce" class="close-btn">Lettuce<a href="#" class="close"></a></span></li>
                  </ul>

                 <ul data-id="Core Filling" class="left">
                    <li>Core Filling</li>
                    <li class="second CoreFilling"><span data-addedname="Steak" class="close-btn">Steak<a href="#" class="close"></a></span><span data-addedname="CrispyChecken" class="close-btn">Crispy Checken<a href="#" class="close"></a></span></li>
                  </ul>

                 <ul data-id="Spreads &amp; Cheeses" class="left">
                    <li>Spreads &amp; Cheeses</li>
                    <li class="second SpreadsCheeses"><span data-addedname="HomemadeHommos(Spread)" class="close-btn">Homemade Hommos (Spread)<a href="#" class="close"></a></span><span data-addedname="ZaatarWithOliveOil(Spread)" class="close-btn">Zaatar With Olive Oil (Spread)<a href="#" class="close"></a></span></li>
                  </ul>

                 <ul data-id="Classic Ingredients" class="left">
                    <li>Classic Ingredients</li>
                    <li class="second ClassicIngredients"><span data-addedname="Lettuce" class="close-btn">Lettuce<a href="#" class="close"></a></span><span data-addedname="Tomato" class="close-btn">Tomato<a href="#" class="close"></a></span><span data-addedname="Cucumber" class="close-btn">Cucumber<a href="#" class="close"></a></span><span data-addedname="Pickles" class="close-btn">Pickles<a href="#" class="close"></a></span></li>
                  </ul>

                 <ul data-id="Premium Ingredients" class="left">
                    <li>Premium Ingredients</li>
                    <li class="second PremiumIngredients"><span data-addedname="SundriedTomato" class="close-btn">Sundried Tomato<a href="#" class="close"></a></span></li>
                  </ul>

                 <ul data-id="Sauces" class="left">
                    <li>Sauces</li>
                    <li class="second Sauces"><span data-addedname="Ketchup*(Classic)" class="close-btn">Ketchup* (Classic)<a href="#" class="close"></a></span><span data-addedname="Mayo(Classic)" class="close-btn">Mayo (Classic)<a href="#" class="close"></a></span></li>
                  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', function() {
        $('.box-ul').find('ul').find('li.Base:first').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Code only answers are not always encouraged. Please provide some explanation also.

Comment: if you want to remove 1st  li which has class name Base when click,